# Implementing an Iterator on Composite Design Pattern Through Separate Class - Is It programmatically valid?

Tags: java, iterator, composite, iterable

I have implemented the Composite Design Pattern and then expanded the Composite class to also implement Iterable, however the iterator() method (which returns an iterator object) is also part of the abstract Component class and is then implemented by the Composite class (but not the Leaf class).

I want to implement a depth first and breadth first search for a tree-like structure. See summarized code below:

```
public abstract class Component {

  public void add() {
  }

  public void remove() {
  }

  public ArrayList<Component> getItems() {
  }

  public ItemIterator iterator() {
  }
```

```
public class Composite extends Component implements Iterable<Component> {

  ArrayList<Component> items = new ArrayList<Component>();
  String name;

  public ItemIterator iterator() {
  return new ItemIterator(this);
  }

  public Composite(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public getName() {
  // returns name
  }

  public ArrayList<Component> getItems() {
  return this.items;
  }
```

```
public class ItemIterator implements Iterator<Component> {

  ArrayList<Component> breadthFirstSearch = new ArrayList<Component>();
  Component currentItem;

  public ItemIterator(Component firstItem) {
  currentItem = firstItem;
  breadthFirstSearch.add(currentItem);
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
  if (breadthFirstSearch.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
  }

  public Component next() {
  // This method pops the root item the first time, creates its children, 
  // places at end of ArrayList,
  // then returns the root. Second time the same operations are performed
  // on the following item in the breadth first traversal of the tree.
  if (hasNext()) {
    Component nextItem = breadthFirstSearch.get(0);
    if (nextItem instanceof Composite) {
      for (Component item : currentItem.getItems()) {
        breadthFirstSearch.add(item);
      }
    }
    breadthFirstSearch.remove(0);
    if (hasNext()) {
      currentItem = breadthFirstSearch.get(0);
    }
    return nextItem;
  }
  return null;
  }
```

```
public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Component bag = new Composite("bag");
    Component plasticBag = new Composite("plastic bag");
    Component makeupBag = new Composite("makeup bag");
    Component phone = new Composite("phone");
    Component lipstick = new Composite("lipstick");
    Component mascara = new Composite("mascara");

    bag.add(plasticBag); bag.add(makeupBag);
    plasticbag.add(phone); makeupBag.add(lipstick); makeupBag.add(mascara);

    ItemIterator itr = bag.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(itr.next().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

The code above compiles and runs fine, it works. However, I am not certain of whether it is programmatically acceptable. The structure of it seems to fundamentally go against other Iterator implementations that I have seen (implementations that I discovered after finishing the above solution), but I can't quite grasp/explain what is so wrong about it. The other way of implementing Iterable (in a different context) was of the form:

```
public abstract class Component {

  public void add() {
  }

  public void remove() {
  }

  public ArrayList<Component> getItems() {
  }
}
```

Note the lack of an iterator() method in the abstract class above.

```
public class Composite extends Component implements Iterable<Component> {

  ArrayList<Component> items = new ArrayList<Component>();
  String name;

  public Iterator<Component> iterator() {

    return new Iterator() {
      public boolean hasNext() {
      // Code
      }

      public Iterator<Component> next() {
      // Code
      };
  }

  public Composite(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public getName() {
  // returns name
  }

  public ArrayList<Component> getItems() {
  return this.items;
  }
}
```

Which way of structuring the solution is better, and is my way of doing it outright wrong/bad practice and if so, why? I am new to Java, so I apologize if this turns out to be a bad question.

Comment: Of course. For inspiration, check out the design at https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/iterator

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having iterator build up a list of pending items to iterate, it should just store a list of pending iterators to traverse.

Here is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```java
public final class Node {
    private final String name;
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Node(String name, Node... children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children.addAll(Arrays.asList(children));
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
    public Iterable<Node> breadthFirstSearch() {
        return () -> new NodeIterator(this, true);
    }
    public Iterable<Node> depthFirstSearch() {
        return () -> new NodeIterator(this, false);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node[" + this.name + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
public final class NodeIterator implements Iterator<Node> {
    private final Deque<Iterator<Node>> iterators = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final boolean breadthFirst;
    public NodeIterator(Node node, boolean breadthFirst) {
        this.iterators.add(Collections.singleton(node).iterator());
        this.breadthFirst = breadthFirst;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return ! this.iterators.isEmpty();
    }
    @Override
    public Node next() {
        Iterator<Node> iterator = this.iterators.removeFirst();
        Node node = iterator.next();
        if (iterator.hasNext())
            this.iterators.addFirst(iterator);
        if (! node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            if (this.breadthFirst)
                this.iterators.addLast(node.getChildren().iterator());
            else
                this.iterators.addFirst(node.getChildren().iterator());
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
Node root = new Node("root",
        new Node("1",
                new Node("1.1",
                        new Node("1.1.1"),
                        new Node("1.1.2")),
                new Node("1.2",
                        new Node("1.2.1"),
                        new Node("1.2.2"))
                ),
        new Node("2",
                new Node("2.1",
                        new Node("2.1.1"),
                        new Node("2.1.2")),
                new Node("2.2",
                        new Node("2.2.1"),
                        new Node("2.2.2"))));
for (Node node : root.breadthFirstSearch())
    System.out.println(node);
System.out.println();
for (Node node : root.depthFirstSearch())
    System.out.println(node);
```

*Output*

```
Node[root]
Node[1]
Node[2]
Node[1.1]
Node[1.2]
Node[2.1]
Node[2.2]
Node[1.1.1]
Node[1.1.2]
Node[1.2.1]
Node[1.2.2]
Node[2.1.1]
Node[2.1.2]
Node[2.2.1]
Node[2.2.2]

Node[root]
Node[1]
Node[1.1]
Node[1.1.1]
Node[1.1.2]
Node[1.2]
Node[1.2.1]
Node[1.2.2]
Node[2]
Node[2.1]
Node[2.1.1]
Node[2.1.2]
Node[2.2]
Node[2.2.1]
Node[2.2.2]
```

Comment: @OleksandrPyrohov *DOH!* Yeah, I did, thanks for letting me know. At least I was consistent in my typo, huh.

Answer (score 0):

I think you described the visitor pattern:

```
interface Visitable {
   void accept(Visitor v);
}

class Visitor {
    void visit(Component c){
        c.doFooBar();// implement your logic here
    }

}

class Component implements Visitable {

    private List<Component> children;

    void accept(Visitor v){
        v.visit(this);
        children.forEach(child -> child.accept(v)); // sumbit the visitor/iterator down the composite tree
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Component composite = Factory.createComposite();
    composite.accept(new Visitor());
}
```